# print multiple regex in python loop, currently only printing one

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below `python 3.7` script, the below code executes but returns no results. However, if I change the `if t is not None:` and `print(t.group())`, I get the match result for only `t`. I can not seem to adjust in to get both match results for `t` and `c`. Thank you :).

**file**

```
00-0000-aa_S6_t_a_a.txt
00-0000-aa_S6_t_a_n_a.csv
00-0000-aa_S6_t_a_n_a.txt
00-0000-aa_S6_t_a_n_m_a.txt
00-0000-aa_S6_t_a_s_a.csv
```

**code**

```
items = obj.key.split("/")                            # split on obj.key / and store in items
if items[2:] and file in items[2]:                      # if the id is in the 3rd field after the split and store in items[2]
    t = re.match(r".*_t_a_n_a.txt, items[2]")         # match regex pattern in items[2]
    c = re.match(r".*_t_a_n_a.csv, items[2]")          # match regex pattern in items[2]
    if t is not None and c is not None:               # ensure t and c have a value
           print(t.group() and c.group())             # print the entire match
```

**desired t then c**

```
00-0000-aa_S6_t_a_n_a.txt
00-0000-aa_S6_t_a_n_a.csv
```

Comment: That is not what `and` is for.  Just do `print(t.group(), c.group())`.  However, you can very easily combine those two into one.  `"...a.(txt|csv),..."`.

Comment: You seem to know that `and` is for combining logical conditions when you use it in `if`. Why do you think it would have some other meaning in `print()`?

Comment: It will never be the case that both regular expressions match on the same line. On line 1, `t` will have a value but `c` will be `None`. The opposite on line 2.

Comment: Your quotes are in the wrong place. It should be `re.match(r".*_t_a_n_a.txt", items[2])`

Comment: What is `obj.key`? How does it relate to the file?

Comment: Sorry, still very new to `python`, `obj.key` is what `file` is before the `split`. Thank you :).

Comment: @TimRoberts, I did not know that was possible... if you put it as an answer I will accept, Thank you :).

Comment: If ALL you want to know is "is this a txt or a csv?" then use `os.path.splitext(items[2])[1]`.  That returns the extension by itself.